# Is PMA is Secure By Default for Shared Hosting? IF not , How To Secure PMA For Shared Hosting

Tags: phpmyadmin, hosting, shared-hosting

I installed Nginx and PMA on Ubuntu and i'm creating a Database AND User for Clients with the following query:

```
CREATE USER '${USER}'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '${password}';GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '${DATABSE}'@'%';ALTER USER '${USER}'@'%' REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 1000 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 1000 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 1000 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 1000;CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${DATABSE};GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${DATABASE}.* TO '${USER}'@'%'
```

i did not touch a single other settings on PMA or MYSQL to limit/restric user's access,
now i am wondering if the created user with the mysql query is restricted so not be able to mess with mysql and PMA settings or other users databases/data?
if not how should i configure mysql and pma to make it secure?
thank you